# drop and resize doesn't seem to works after a first resizing, with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

good morning dev' :-)

If I mouse up after the first resizing, I can't resize anymore... And, after that first resizing, I can't drop that div too...

I use Laravel and jQuery.

See [the jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YtCNm/)

I would like to be able to resizing again and again...

Here the JS code (jsFiddle will show you the entire code) :

```
$("#creneau"+i+"-"+j).droppable({
    appendTo: "body",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    accept: ".external-event",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var draggableEvent = null;
        if($(ui.draggable).hasClass("cloneable")){
            var drg = ui.draggable.clone();
            $(drg).addClass("moveable");
            $(drg).removeClass("cloneable");
            drg.resizable({
                handles: 'e, w',
                        resize: function(event, ui) {
                            $(this).empty();
                            $(this).append($(this).position().left);
                            $(this).append("<div style=\"z-index: 90; display: block;\" class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e\"></div>");
                            $(this).append("<div style=\"z-index: 90; display: block;\" class=\"ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w\"></div>");
                        }
            });
            drg.draggable({
                appendTo: "#hours-creneau",
                cursor: "move",
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: "invalid"
            });
            draggableEvent = $(ui.draggable);
        }else if($(ui.draggable).hasClass("moveable")){
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
            draggableEvent = $(ui.draggable);
        }
        $(this).append(drg);
    }
});
```

And the html :

```
        <div id='external-events'>

            <h4>Draggable States</h4>

                <span class='external-event cloneable'>State1</span>
                <span class='external-event cloneable'>State2</span>
                <span class='external-event cloneable'>State3</span>
                <span class='external-event cloneable'>State4</span>

        </div>
        <div id="tables-events">

            <div id="hours-creneau">
                <div id="hours"></div>
                <div id="creneau" class="draggable"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT : ANSWERED MYSELF**

I can't post an answer yet, but I edit this message :

First, the div seems to add "top, left and absolute css" when resizing. So I removed the left and top, with :

```
$(this).css("top", "");
$(this).css("left", "");
```

and drop works again after resizing.

And for the resizing disabled after first resize, it was because I append text in the div... Don't know really why but it 'broke' the resizable event.

Thanks guys for trying to help me.

Comment: I noticed `ui-resizable-handle` class is removed after the first resize.

Comment: Thanks. I rewrite that in the code, (Updated post) but it doesn't change the problem. It just add the possibility to "resize", with a cursor change at hover, but I can't resize.

Comment: this has nothing to do with laravel or php or anything related to server side.

Comment: I think that to give most possible information remains useful. I just tagged with "Laravel" because I use laravel for this project. Anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered myself, I share the answer.

First, the div seems to add "top, left and absolute css" when resizing. So I removed the left and top, with :

```
$(this).css("top", "");
$(this).css("left", "");
```

and drop works again after resizing.

And for the resizing disabled after first resize, it was because I append text in the div... Don't know really why but it 'broke' the resizable event.

Thanks guys for trying to help me.